# Removing trailing ok from io:format in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am building a simple tic tac toe program in Erlang. I pass the board as a string to `io:format("123\n456\n789\n")` and want to see:

```
123
456
789
```

But in the Erlang shell `io:format("123\n456\n789\n")` prints this:

```
123
456
789
ok
```

Is there a way to output to the console without the trailing ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ok` is there to tell you that the call worked. The spec for the function [io:format](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1) specifies this.

The real problem here is that you are seeing a mixture of the erlang terminal, and whatever is comming from stdout - stdout is printing the numbers, and the erlang terminal is giving back the `ok`.

if you were writing a script using escript, the ok stratement will not be printed to standart output - you should simply think of the console as an interactive interpreter.

As a side note the easiest way to output:

```
123
456
789
```

Would be

```
1> 123. 456. 789.
123
456
789
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the shell, who prints that last `ok` atom. Try this:

```
erl -noshell -eval 'io:format("123\n456\n789\n"),init:stop()'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Erlang shell is a REPL, a Read/Eval/Print Loop. It reads a typed in expression, evaluates it, prints the result and loops to read the expression. The important thing to remember is that you enter an expression which **always returns a value** and the shell **always prints the value**. You cannot not return a value!

So when you enter `io:format("123\n456\n789\n").` the shell evaluates the expression and prints the result. Evaluating the call to `io:format` results in the string being printed out and the call returns the value `ok` which the shell prints out. Hence you get

```
123
456
789
ok
```

Again the shell always prints the value returned by the expression. If you call `io:format` from within another function then its return value will generally not be returned to shell and the shell will not print it out.

Note that returning a value and printing something are two completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround (`It's just for fun:)`):

```
> spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(1000), io:format("123\n456\n789\n") end).
<0.77.0>
123 
456
789
```